# value of extern variable

Tags: c, extern

I'm programming in C for firmware.

I have a header file: `extern.h`:

```
extern int x;
```

And I have `file1.c`:

```
#include"extern.h"
//----------foo1 gives value to x------------------------

foo1(void)
{
    int x=200;  
}
```

Now I have `foo2` in `file2.c`

```
#include"extern.h"

foo2(void)
{
    int x;
    printf("%d",x);
}
```

And finally in `main.c`

```
#include"extern.h"

void main()
{
    foo1();
    foo2();  
}
```

What could be the problem if get junk values in execution?
I trust the value of the variable must be 200.

I did a similar thing via `mplab c18` and instead of `printf` in `foo2.c`, I did a transmission to the GUI function in `foo2.c`  and it shows  random int values in thousands and ten thousands..completely not related to the 200 that I gave.

And when i did initialize 'x' as

```
   foo2(void)
   {
        int x;
   }
```

It again shows random value in thousands.

I trust this not a problem with the coding i have done as it must transmit 200.

Note:

> But on counter of that if initialize and transmit in foo2.c then the
>   values are displayed correctly.

Where should I look for bugs: in the GUI or in the Firmware?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say `extern int x`, it means that it is a global variable which is going to be defined in some other .c file. The local variables you have defined in foo1 and foo2 have precedence over the global extern variable. In foo1 the value of x will be 200 and in foo2 the value of x can be any value depending on what was there on the stack. Also I do not see where you have actually defined x to be a global variable. That is missing too.

Comment: so the data on foo2 can not be 200 right.even if include the headerfile right.And how should i make it 200?.By omitting declaration inside foo2?

Comment: Yes, you should remove the int declaration of x inside foo2 if you want the global variable x to take effect inside foo2. But you have to somewhere define x to be a global variable in one of the .c file which is also missing in the code which you have shown.

Comment: when i remove x, the compiler c18 says so "Error - could not find definition of symbol 'x' in file './build/default/production/main.o'."

Comment: You need to define it as a global variable in one of your .c files. Include "int x" before your `void main()`

Answer (score 1):

foo1() -> does nothing

foo2() -> declares a variable x, which is UNDEFINED (no value has been set to it), so it could be anything.

Variables declared like `int x;` only have a lifetime of the scope they are in, i.e. you can't use the same name everywhere and expect it will map to the same variable.

If your variable is a global extern, don't redeclare it in the local `foo` functions you have.

See also
[How do I use extern to share variables between source files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-share-a-variable-between-source-files-in-c-with-extern-but-how)

Comment: So if omit redeclaration inside foo2 it will retain the value?

Comment: It will if you omit the redefinition of the variable, but you haven't declared any space/memory for the int, so you need to say `extern int x;` then under that `int x = 0;`

Answer (score 1):

When you place the line `extern int x;` in your `extern.h` file, what you're stating is that there exists an `x` somewhere but *not* here (well, not here unless you also have an `int x;` as well in the same scope).

In other words, it's a *declaration* that something exists rather than a *definition* that creates that something. So, without a definition, that particular `x` is never created.

In both your `foo1()` and `foo2()` functions, you *do* create something called `x`, however it's *not* the same `x` as the one you've declared in `extern.h`: it has different scope.

Both the `x` in `foo1()` and `foo2()` (and they are *distinct* variables, not the same one) are local to the function they're defined in. Hence `foo1()` creates its `x`, sets the value of it to `200` then throws that away on exit.

`foo2()`, on the other hand, creates its `x` with an *arbitrary* value and then prints it (hence your "junk value" comment).

That explains the behaviour you're seeing, now how to fix that. The way this is normally done is to *define* the variable somewhere (only once) and *declare* it wherever it's used, something like:

```
extern.h:
    extern int x;         // declare it
    void foo1(void);
    void foo2(void);

foo1.c:
    #include "extern.h"   // declare x via the header

    void foo1(void) {
        x = 200;          // set x, note: no int at start of line
                          //   since that would create a NEW x.
    }

foo2.c:
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include "extern.h"   // declare x via the header

    void foo2(void) {
        printf "%d\n", x);  // again, no "int x;" since that would
                            //   create a NEW x.
    }

main.c:
    #include "extern.h"   // declare in the header
    int x;                // and define it.

    int main (void) {
        foo1();
        foo2();
        return 0;
    }
```

So the "global" `x` exists in `main.c` (though you could put it in any of the C files, as long as it's only in *one* of them). The fact that both `foo1.c` and `foo2.c` include the `extern.h` header that declares the existence of `x` means that they'll be able to find it.

By ensuring that neither `foo1()` nor `foo2()` *define* another `x` in local scope (by using `int x;` or `int x = something;`), they'll use the `x` at the next outer scope (i.e, the one in `main.c`).

---

When you define an inner-scope variable of the same name as an outer scope one, the former "hides" (or "shadows") the latter. For example, the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void) {
    int x = 42;
    printf ("A: %8d\n", x);
    {
        int x = 314159;
        printf ("B: %8d\n", x);
    }
    printf ("C: %8d\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

will output:

```
A:       42
B:   314159
C:       42
```

as the inner braces create a new `x` within that scope. And, when the scope ends, the `x` you see then is the *original* one.

Comment: i  did the same but unfortunalely I could not get the results. I got this error from the c18 compiler "Error - could not find definition of symbol 'x' in file './build/default/production/main.o'."

Comment: @Rookie91: then you haven't defined it. I suggest you look at the code again, specifically the bit in `main.c` that says `int x;`.

Comment: if i declare that as extern in header file. Why is it necessary that i have to declare it as global int 'x' so in main.c

Comment: @Rookie, you may want to read the answer again. The thing in the header file is a declaration, it does _not_ create `x`. `int x;` in `main.c` is a **definition** that _does_ create `x`. You must _define_ it somewhere.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clearing my doubt and for your time :)

Comment: @Rookie, no probs, glad I could help.